# why are some functions on open intervals not bounded above?

Tags: real-analysis

So we are given

Let $f:[a,b]\to \Bbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Then $f$ is bounded above; that is there exists $M \in \Bbb{R}$, such that for all $x \in [a,b]$ we have $f(x) \le M$

The problem I am dealing with is proving

$f:(a,b) \to \Bbb{R}$ must f be bounded above?

I know the answer is no as a specific example can disprove this.

Take $f:(0,1)$ with $f(x) =$ 1/x. Then prove by contradiction. Assume $M$ is the upper bound. $M \gt 0$ and for all $x \in (0,1)$ we have $f(x) \le M$. Consider $x = \frac{1}{(M+1)}$ then $\frac{1}{(M+1)} \in (0,1)$. So $f(x) = M + 1 \gt M$. Hence $M$ is not the upper bound.

My problem is doesn't this mean there is no upper bound for $f:[0,1] \to \Bbb{R}$ with $f(x) =$ 1/x as well? The above contradiction would seem to hold on this function as well. What am I missing? Is it because $f(x)$ is not continuous at $0$ hence the statement does not hold. And as the interval $(0,1)$ does not include $0$ then the function $f:(0,1)$ is continuous as it doesnt include $0$?

Comment: If you define $f\colon[0,1]\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ by $f(x)=\frac1x$, then what is $f(0)$?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly because $\frac1x$ is not continuous at $0$ that the theorem you quote can't be applied.

Comment: Thanks @Henriksupportsthecommunity - I was baffling over this all morning!

Answer (score 0):

You might be confused with some definitions. First of all, the function $f:(0,1)\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ can not be said to be continious or discontinious at $x=0$, since it is not defined at this point (the interval $(0,1)$ does not contain $0$). Nevertheless, $f$ is continious in $(0,1)$, where it is defined.

Regarding the result you mentioned, that is, every continious function $f:[0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bounded, depends on two key facts: $f$ is continious and the interval $[0,1]$ is compact. In case you do not know what a compact interval is, for simplicity in this case, is a closed and bounded interval (for instance, the interval $(0,1)$ or $[-3,\infty)$ are not compact).

Now, lets build some intuition about why does the result holds when a continious function $f$ is deifined in $[0,1]$ and does not hold when it is defined in $(0,1)$. If $f$ is defined in $[0,1]$, it forces $f$ to be finite (therefore bounded) at $x=0$ and at $x=1$. Now, if $f(0)\geq f(x)$ or $f(1)\geq f(x)$ for all $x\in[0,1]$, we have that $f$ is bounded from above. If that is not the case, then, since it is bounded at $x=0$ and $x=1$, it can not "grow up to infinity", since it is continious and that would mean that that has an asymptote, so there must exists at least a point $x_0\in(0,1)$ such that $f(x_0)\geq f(x)$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. A similar reasoning follow in order to bound the function from below. Notice thath this all come from the fact that at least we have two boundry points (that is, $x=0$ and $x=1$) where $f$ is bounded, and we do not have that in case that $f$ is defined at $(0,1)$.

If we want to be formal, there are two results that is pretty helpful.

**Proposition:** *A set $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is compact is and only if and only if for every sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq S$ there is a subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}_{n_k\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq S$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n_k\to\infty}a_{n_k}\in S$.*

**Proposition:** *Let $f:S\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continious function defined in some set $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and let $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq S$ be a convergent sequence such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L$. Then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=f(L)$.*

Using this two facts (you can check the proofs of both results, for instance, in *Calculus I* of Apostol) we can prove the result and you will see in a formal manner why it is important the the interval is closed. By contradiction, suppose that there is a continious function $f:[0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that it is not bounded above. That is, there exists no constant $M>0$ such that $f(x)\leq M$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Let $n$ be a natural number, then it is not true that $f(x)\leq n$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. So, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists at least an element $x_n\in[0,1]$ such that $f(x_n)>n$. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ pick an element $x_n$ as before (there can be many possibilities to choose, but just pick one). Then we have a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in[0,1]$. Since $[0,1]$ is compact, there exists a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}_{n_k\in\mathbb{N}}$ of $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that it converges $x_{n_k}\longrightarrow L\in[0,1]$. Since $f$ is continious and $L\in[0,1]$, the sequence $\{f(x_{n_k})\}_{n_k\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $f(L)$ and $f(L)<\infty$, but this is a contradiction, because by construction, $f(x_{n_k})>n_k$, so $f(L)$ can not be bounded. Hence the result.

I hope this quite extended answer serves you well. If you have any doubt, do not hesitate to ask me.